# Snap arrows to center of circle (ellipse) in Dia

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, dia

In Dia, however hard I try, I can not put my arrow ends to the center of a circle (ellipse). See this diagram here.

[image]

For the top arrow, however hard I try to move the end to circle center (on a grid), it moves back to the position shown, which is just on the circumference of the circle. As you can see, 
the bottom arrow is easily placed at the grid intersection.

Could you please tell me how can I move the arrow end to circle center?

I have tried turning on and off `Snap to object`.

I am using Dia in Ubuntu 12.04, dia-normal 0.97.2.

*(The grid lines you see here have been drawn by me).*

Comment: Please remember to always include the Operating System you are using. Dia has versions for Linux, MacOS X, and Windows (and you cab get it for Solaris and Irix). Also, please include the version of dia that you are using.

Comment: @terdon Edited.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two things you could do to overcome your problem:

- Place arrows and circles in different layers
- Open the arrow properties and add negative values for "Absolute start gap" and "Absolute end gap"

If you know how to create shapes, you could create a circular shape without a main connection point in the center (but a normal connection point). This would allow your arrows to connect to the center in the way you intend. If you don't want to get involved in shape creation I could also provide you with such a shape.

Comment: In the first case, does the arrow move if I move the circle?

Comment: No, in that case, the two object are not connected to each other and thus move indepently.